# How to select a minimal value from a joined table with JPA?

Tags: sql, select, jpa, join

I would like to **select** the **country** where a person lives **and** his **oldest/original country.**

This example has 2 tables:

- *PERSON* with personal information and his current country
- *HISTORY* with the *historical countries* of the person. They are ordered by ID (so I didn't have to add a date for this simple example).

I use something like this in SQL:

```
SELECT p.COUNTRY, h.HISTORY
FROM COUNTRY AS c, HISTORY as h
WHERE c.ID = h.PERSON
AND h.ID = (SELECT MIN(h2.ID) FROM HISTORY as h2 WHERE h2.ID = name.ID)
```

**Is this how I should do this with JPA?** (The Entity objects are at the end of my question).

```
SELECT p.country, p.historyEntity.history
FROM PersonEntity AS p
WHERE MIN(p.historyEntity.id)
```

Thanks! Any advice is welcome.

```
Table: PERSON
ID    |    Name    |   COUNTRY
------------------------------
1     |    John    |   USA
2     |    Maria   |   CANADA
3     |    Peter   |   FRANCE

Table: HISTORY
ID    | PERSON (FK)|   HISTORY
------------------------------
1     |    1       |   MEXICO
2     |    1       |   BRASILIA
3     |    1       |   USA
4     |    2       |   GERMANY
5     |    2       |   CANADA
6     |    3       |   JAPAN
7     |    3       |   KOREA
8     |    3       |   USA


@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class PersonEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "COUNTRY")
    private String country;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "historyEntity")
    private Set<HistoryEntity> historyEntities = new HashSet<HistoryEntity>(0);

...
}

@Table(name = "HISTORY")
public class HistoryEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON")
    private PersonEntity personEntity;
    @Column(name = "HISTORY")
    private String history;

...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you know that your query doesn't work... Try this one:

```
SELECT p.country, h.history
FROM PersonEntity AS p
JOIN p.historyEntity h
WHERE h.id IN (SELECT MIN(h2.id) FROM HistoryEntity h2 where h2.historyEntity=p GROUP BY historyEntity)
```